# read parquet files in a folder with _SUCCESS

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, pyarrow

Use pyarrow to read parquet files in a folder with _SUCCESS file

```
gs://abcdbucket/TABLE/_SUCCESS
gs://abcdbucket/TABLE/part-00000-15f7509d-cac8-4c2-8bb1-x1x2x-c000.gz.parquet
gs://abcdbucket/TABLE/part-00001-15f7509d-cac8-4c2-8bb1-x1x2x-c000.gz.parquet
```

pyarrow version - 12.0.0

Currently I am trying the below code:

```
gs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
df_cogs = pyarrow.parquet.read_table("abcdbucket/TABLE", filesystem=gs)
```

It fails with raise FileNotFoundError(path)

Comment: Can you provide the full error message? The error FileNotFoundError(path) can be caused by the parquet file not being accessible or if it's not found. 

If error is related to access issue, its best to revisit the file permission of your parquet files.